# Feature request on commenting vs editing with a reputation value under 50

Tags: feature-request, comments, new-users

My questions are these:

1. If I am unable to post a comment until I have achieved a reputation value of 50, how do I ask a question regarding an answer to a topic that I feel would be useful to others?
2. Why can I edit a response, but not comment on one when my reputation is below 50?

I would suggest the following

1. Comments be allowed to those with low reputation, but require a moderator to approve them.
2. If too many comments are denied, then the ability to comment is lost.
3. Perhaps make this an option that must be requested and would have to be enabled by a moderator/administrator before commenting is allowed.
4. Allow moderators/administrators to adjust a user's reputation based on their comments with a reason.  I recommend that it would be a dedicated list of reasons to limit any kind of personal differences.
5. Editing should also not be allowed for those with a low reputation.

I can understand the concern that comments could be used to spam, but so could editing.

Edits need to be approved, so it makes sense to me that comments could follow the same path and restrictions.

Comment: Please research before considering posting a question. If you ask, reflect your research.

Comment: I did try to find something that addressed this, but I had a hard time.  Perhaps I used a bad criteria.

Comment: Thank you for helping to identify a closely linked topic.

Comment: I do not understand the "Rule #1" comment in that topic "Do not ask for clarification in an answer".  If the answer is unclear to me then it is useless.  I know the purpose is for one person to get answers from the community, but those answers can help the rest of the community, but not if only the requestor and responder understand it.  And asking again has the potential to get the question marked as a duplicate and get you negative reputation.  I believe that this would tend to make users choose not to do this.

Comment: @Shaggie I think it means: Do not post an Answer asking for clarifications of the Question. Answers should only be used to answer. It doesn't mean: Do not comment on an Answer :)

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense.  I would not want to do that anyway.  I don't know why I took it as "of an answer".

Comment: More accurately, I was thinking "against an Answer", for which you helped to clarify was a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: I think one reason I didn't see that related post is because it was created 6 years ago.  It was active several months ago, but I don't recall the automatic search making that high enough in the suggestions of related topics for me to see it.  I did have a different title at first though.

Comment: With the perhaps 100s of millions of articles on stack overflow, people will try to search through the existing posts but sometimes it can just feel overwhelming trying to find something relevant.  I am usually much better than some of my colleagues on finding things, but I experience this at times as well.

Comment: SO/SE search is poor. Google with site:meta.stackoverflow.com & site:meta.stackexchange.com'. Google re advanced googling.  See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment.

Comment: @philipxy I am quite familiar with advanced googling, although sometimes it gives me extra stuff that I do not want, like a page that is linked to a page that contains my search terms.  I would have thought that SO/SE would have a good search, especially if insufficient research is a reason to take issue with a post.  Thank you for pointing that out.  I was using the search built into the site.  IMHO they should work on that.  Some sites actually just use Google or another search engine for their searches.

Answer (score 12):

The answers to your questions:

1. You can't.
2. At less than 2000 reputation, that's not editing; it's *suggested editing,* which must still be approved by multiple community members.

Some thoughts on your suggestions:

1. Getting moderator approval for comments would take awhile.  I'm guessing the average response time for diamond moderators on Stack Overflow nowadays is somewhere between 1 and 4 hours.

2., 3., 4., ... It looks like you basically want to build a brand new subsystem to accomodate brand new users, rather than giving them some time to become familiar with the site and how it works first.

Editing to spam is a fruitless activity.  It would quickly be reverted by community members.

Unfortunately a lot of new users bring their bad forum habits with them, so it's necessary to give them a little time to acclimate.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on editing.  I was unaware there was a difference.

Still, I would think that comments could be treated in the same manner.

Also, I wouldn't consider myself a brand new user, just because I haven't created many posts.

In one particular case, I wanted to point out that a link was no longer available because Microsoft took it down, and ask if they had any further information.
To me, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: So basically, you are saying that if a post is missing information, or information has been lost, there is no way for newer users to ask about this?  That seems very unhelpful to me for new users.  I don't see how that would encourage them to use this system.

Comment: New users aren't the only ones using the system.  There are plenty of users over 50 rep who can ask for clarification.

Comment: I have used stack overflow for years, but haven't had to ask questions previously because they are often already answered.  There have been times where I wanted to comment on something, but because I have not posted questions myself, I was unable to.  Until recently, I just decided to forget about it.  Other users with a higher rep apparently don't have the same questions I do.

Comment: There are so many posts on Stack Overflow, I can't imagine that all are re-reviewed later to see if information has been lost or needs further clarification.  I know sometimes that some people can understand what is being said, but others, often due to the specific language/grammar/whatever have a hard time understanding.

Comment: My intention was to allow stack overflow to be more inclusive, to be more encouraging for users to contribute to the system.

Comment: That's a much larger problem.

Comment: By the way I did start with flag this as a discussion/feature request. But someone else removed the discussion part.

Comment: Oh, for clarification, when I said having a moderator approve comments, I actually meant using the same system that suggested edits uses.  I was not concerned with it taking time for approval.  If you would rather have a different level of user do this, then that is acceptable to me.  It does seem like this suggested change is unlikely to proceed though.

Comment: Hopefully this is my last comment on the subject unless someone else wants to continue this further.  I don't consider new users to be the same as people who have visited/used the site for years but have contributed very little.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/397991