# There should be separate comment reputation points on this particular community

Tags: feature-request, comments

**Up front edit to point out that downvotes and existing questions do not address any of the points I have made. I will tweak my post to reflect accurate comment functionality, but the point remains the same, and unanswered.**

I have been using Stack Overflow for a really long time (although only for about 2.5 years with an account). Only in the past day did I get enough reputation points to comment on answers and questions, although this *would* have been my primary mode of interaction with the site over the years, if I had the ability.

**PROPOSED SOLUTION**

Have an aggressive and separate rate limit allowance on comments and the reputation points associated with them. Say you're new to the site, you have a 5 comment allowance. If your comments are neutral (not upvoted), you get 5 new comments every *n* amount of time (once a month, maybe even once year?). If you get comments that are upvoted, you earn a new comment for every comment upvote (or something like that).

I think this or something similar would improve site functionality dramatically, making it far more welcoming to newcomers and people who have the good sense to know who the experts are and that they aren't one of them, without clogging the site with bad comments.

**ANTICIPATING PUSHBACK**

**Why so long to get reputation points?**

I mostly find the answers in existing Q&A's on this site! That's a good thing. There are lots of questions and lots of answers out there, and most of the time people like me can find what we need. The inability to upvote useful answers while using the site with only 1 solitary reputation point is frustrating, but nonetheless tolerable. (I do believe upvotes should be allowed for people new to the site, I don't think coding advice is the type of thing people upvote when it's unhelpful. But that isn't the point of this post). Stack Overflow is unique among the Stack Exchange communities when it comes to earning reputation points because of the proliferation of common questions and the objectivity of what a successful answer looks like.

**Why have separate comment reputation?**

Quite often I have needed to ask for clarification on an existing answer that it is almost all the way there. Asking a new question would inevitably be labeled as a duplicate. As a result, I then have to do more searching to find the details I need. This is frustrating, time consuming, and I think a major flaw in how this site works.

**Why not add an answer or edit to get the reputation points?**

By way of example, on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35559074/9237603), I knew that there was a built in `colors.to_hex()` method. This would make an appropriate comment. Editing the answer is, in my opinion, out of line, and unhelpful. The method the user included was very informative - it's a great example of how to convert RGBA to hex. It still lets the user know what the correct solution would be. Any edits to the answer would either require restructuring the entire answer (which is way too much work/very presumptuous) or would be hacky (an edit at the end saying "to_hex()" exists; in my opinion it's better to see this information in a comment).

Adding an answer is a whole other level of knowledge and effort. People who could use comment functionality effectively to ask for clarification or point out additional information on an answer may be several years out from feeling like they could answer any questions better than, or different from, existing answers. This was my case. In the above-linked question, I think I could now provide an answer, but it would require a lot of work for possibly no payout (no reputation points). Doing this to just get comment access creates a large barrier to many people. I thankfully finally had a new question I couldn't find anywhere on the site yet, and that's the only reason I am able to post here.

**Edit**

The site has reminders everywhere to not be hostile to new users, but nobody follows through on this. Everything about proposing a solution to the problem faced by many beginners is met with hostility instead of solution-seeking behavior. Aggressive downvoting for a question that does not deserve it (no comments were left giving the only useful feedback I have received so far - to account for spam in my suggestion, which I already partially accounted for - just answers and downvotes. What is wrong with people? This experience is awful.)

Regarding comments and spam, you mean to tell me that a programming site can't auto-detect spam comments? Even with human-guided machine learning? I'm fairly sure Twitter and plenty of other sites manage spam this way. "Use your time to copy edit the site to earn commenting privileges", they say. Well, what stops a bot from running questions and answers through a grammar check to be able to get commenting privileges? Nothing much. MS Word now has contextual edits - it catches doubled words (has for a while), tells you if you've used the wrong part of speech in a sentence, etc. Meanwhile, this arbitrary restriction is penalizing non-spam users of the site, and for what? Comments can be contributions just like anything else can be. Spam = bad. I agree. But why not lock an account that has even one spam comment reported? And all accounts that upvote it? All of this behavior should be incredibly easy to manage. I genuinely don't think it's the massive hurdle people are pretending it is.

Comment: Comments can't be downvoted, and deletion doesn't necessarily mean it was a bad comment (maybe it was just no longer needed, for example).

Comment: You could also make 25 good edits to current posts that needs editing and gain reputation enough to make a comment. If answering is not your thing, that is. You can find editing guidelines on the FAQ index in the help center.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Feature request on commenting vs editing with a reputation value under 50](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397950/feature-request-on-commenting-vs-editing-with-a-reputation-value-under-50)

Comment: @Scratte, I addressed why this wasn't a good solution in my post.

Comment: @gnat, no, it does not. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment) is closer, but it still didn't have any good answers.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I had thought the red and blue numbers next to comments indicated up and downvotes, I guess I was mistaken. If that's the case, my point remains the same. Upvoted comments could earn more comments, otherwise the rate limit could be incredibly extended for new comment quotas.

Comment: @lead You gave an example of an answer for which editing didn't make sense. Not examples of editing grammar and phrasing on posts that really needs it.

Comment: @Scratte earning reputation points through copy editing doesn't seem relevant to this community. I understand that's a public service that the community wants to exist, but it really doesn't solve the problem. If you think I should further edit my post to reflect this fact, I am willing to do that.

Comment: You could add in that explanation for why you won't edit posts but I don't think it helps your case.

Comment: What you are proposing is getting the ability to comments, by commenting. Not by adding any contributions that are here to stay. Why should you gain privileges to the site, if you do not wish to contribute?

Comment: it looks like your fundamental misunderstanding is a belief that editing is not relevant here. I got my first 200 or 300 rep points here with edits. And if memory serves I got first few hundreds rep points at other Stack Exchange sites where I am active the same way. Not only editing is relevant - it is most convenient, safe and reliable way to gain initial reputation. And it also helps you learn how to better gain more rep with answers and questions along the way

Comment: @lead please [edit] your proposal to explain how it solves the reason for 50 rep limit - preventing spam comments. (Side note: highlighting the fact you are not willing to make an effort to provide content as answers since it requires effort does not make the proposal more convincing... you may want to reword some of the proposal to look less lazy)

Comment: @Scrattle I think comments are contributions. I don't understand the hostility associated with comments.

Comment: @gnat, two separate things. 1, there are mixed messages about comments/edits. Some things people insist should be done in edits, others insist is meant for comments, or new answers. These same things, other people insist are for the other things. 2. Editing isn't relevant because other people have told me it isn't relevant. Look at thecomment from Scrattle: *You gave an example of an answer for which editing didn't make sense. Not examples of editing grammar and phrasing on posts that really needs it.*

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, once more, I think comments can be a form of contribution, and I think before I edit the post unnecessarily, you could perhaps explain how having 5 comments a month/3 months whatever is going to lead to spamming?

Comment: @lead One comment regarding your edit "_Aggressive downvoting for a question that does not deserve it_" - Are you aware that downvotes on feature requests on meta often mean disagreement with the proposed change? It's not aggressive.

Comment: you are expected to do useful edits on good posts. Study how successful editors do that ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63550/peter-mortensen?tab=activity&sort=revisions)) and learn to do like they do. That's what I meant when I wrote that it will help you gain more rep from your own questions and answers, you will learn how people expect good posts to look like and how you can write such posts yourself

Comment: *The site has reminders everywhere to not be hostile to new users, but nobody follows through on this*. I have not been hostile here. I have spent time to explain why I did not agree with you, and have insisted that votes on meta were used by the community to say whether we agree or not with a proposal. As I have already said, I understand your point of view, and think that the current question is fine in proposing a change in SO rules. Simply I do not agree with it, and most of voters do not either.

Comment: We want answers to questions instead of commentary to a question.  Since you can (almost) always submit commentary to your own answer.  *The site also has reminders to limit the amount of commentary you submit but nobody follows through on that either.*

Comment: @Modus Tollens The aggressive downvotes are all by people who have the ability to even comment in the meta. It's inherently hostile to people who are kept out of meta commentary who would agree with me. These people also are the group who couldn't upvote my feature request even if they wanted to. How can you all not see how circular this all is? Only people who agree with you will be here participating.

Comment: @gnat, I didn't need that. Not everybody needs training in good question writing. Some people are ready to go with useful comments. Surely there's some way to work with both types of people instead of penalizing one over the other. I prefer function over style, and you're asking me to participate in style over function.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, I do not understand how so few people understand that everybody here are people who made it through the existing system just fine. The people who are kept out are not allowed to vote! I am representing that voice, and the hostility is coming from people failing to understand the circular logic of all this.

Comment: @Security Hound, can you explain to me why comments that would improve an existing answer wouldn't be enormously helpful? I can't edit in an improvement I don't know about. I can't ask a duplicate question or I"ll get a "this is a duplicate question to this other one that has answers you can't comment on because you don't have enough points yet". You are all systematically keeping out the voices of people in my position, which I was in for YEARS.

Comment: @lead - What kind of comments?  Why are you not suggesting those improvements yourself to the contribution?  What type of comments are we talking about exactly?  If you are talking about asking additional questions, as commentary to an answer, that absolutely should not be done.  Can you provide an example of those enormously helpful commentary?  Don't lump me into the pool of Stack Overflow users.  I have not been an active member of that particular Stack Exchange community for years.  I am only here as a representative of another community.  **I don't see how my downvote was aggressive.**

Comment: @SecurityHound, it happens so often, it's like asking me to identify the components of the air I breathe. Think of any classroom you've ever been in - can you imagine if only the people acing the class could ask for clarification from the professor or teacher? It would be a disaster. This is the way SO operates. It's *coding*, not some controversial topic. Anytime people want clarity, it'll improve the answer. People who don't have the knowledge to answer their own question can't edit to improve the clarity otherwise.

Comment: @lead: I do not want to be rude of offensive. I have read your arguments and I think I have understood them. Yet I do not agree with you. If you want to participate in a community, then you have to accept the community rules. Said differently I really do not want to give comment or direct edit priviledges to people that do not accept the community rules. This is my conception of how a democratic community can be ruled. I apologize if I am not clear here but English is not my first language: I know how to write technical English, but I am less proficient when it comes to ideas.

Comment: @Security Hound, regarding your edit to your comment, the collection of downvotes is aggressive. The collection of people who *can* downvote and upvote and comment here are collectively being aggressive and hostile towards a proposed solution to a problem that the categorically voiceless on this site cannot contribute.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, let's focus on the logic then, because logic is the same in every language. Do you think it's a good idea to have a classroom where only the students who already understand the material just fine are the only ones who can ask questions of the teacher?

Comment: @lead: it is perfectly fine to ask a new question asking for clarification by just refering to an existing question and answer and explaining why you cannot use it directly or why you thing that it does not apply to your specific use case. It may be closed as a duplicate, but it should not be without explainations for your own question. I have already posted a new answer to the original question *with all the details required by the new question* and left a comment in the new question with a link to the new answer....

Comment: @lead - You have not provided a single example of this enormously helpful commentary.  If it would be that helpful, you should be providing an answer to the question, so everyone can upvote that enormously helpful information.  I have extensive knowledge of programming, I was a active member of this community for nearly a decade.  I typically would just answer a question, by submitting an answer, instead of submitting a comment to a question.  **When I wasn't able to comment, to seek clarification, I would just answer a question I could answer without requesting additional information.**

Comment: ... IMHO it has both helped the new asker and improved the site with a new answer focusing on a different use case. And it was easier for me to post that answer, because the question could contain code and data while it would have been impossible in a comment. I do not feel rude to newcomers or to users that are just learning in acting that way. But I begin to think that **you** are aggressive when you never take into account what **we** tell you.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta what you are describing is an organizational nightmare. I am not asking for clarification on the question. Questions typically match what I'm looking for. I am asking for clarity on an existing answer. A desire for a generalized case, or a more clear explanation of what a given method does. Etc. I have not been foolishly using this site, if it were easier to get a question answered by asking a new one, I would have done that. But new questions take a lot more work than the comment+clarification would take. It wastes precious time some people don't have.

Comment: @lead: you may not want to waste your time in asking questions. But then I do not want to waste *my* time in handling comments...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, I have said nothing rude this entire time. People keep claiming I'm being rude, and I have not said a single rude thing. So what I am instead hearing is that people do not like having their perceptions challenged. If I am being aggressive, it is because I have a position that nobody who would support me, is able to support me. Nobody has come up with solutions to the problems I have posed. Not a single person! I spent years with these problems. Other people have them too. Solutions, not dismissal, please.

Comment: @lead - What you describe, is using the comment section under an answer, in order to ask your own question.  That isn't allowed even when you are able to submit commentary.  That is the exact type of commentary that will be flagged and deleted.  You need to be submitting a new question, indicating specifically that the existing answer does not answer your question, and more importantly the reasons that is the case.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, you are wasting a LOT of time handling comments. There are so many people who you are expecting to waste time in various ways, whether searching through similar questions for an answer to their problem, or doing minor edits when what they need is coding help, or people asking a whole new question when an existing answer is 95% of the way there. These are all the people you can't listen to because of existing rules.

Comment: @Security Hound, I have repeatedly told you, and others, this is not something that is worthy of a new question. It is about clarification on existing answers, for the most part. Why you can't imagine this is the case or when it would come up, is a pretty clear indication to me why this continues to be a problem. Everybody who could help me explain this to you is not allowed to comment here.

Comment: @lead - I have been in your shoes.  I have asked my own questions on Stack Overflow.  The difference I suppose, is I actually have asked my own questions, instead of submitting commentary under an answer.

Comment: @lead: Do not think we do not understand your problem. I know how frustrating it can be not to have enough rep to comment or vote. Simply I cannot imagine a perfect system and I think the current one to be an acceptable balance. More exactly I do not want the system you have proposed. If you can imagine a way to allow new users to post comments with no increase in spam or moderation, then I could support it. But with what you have proposed, my opinion is that the risk is higher than the possible gain.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, when you don't try something different out, you have no way of knowing what it will do to moderation loads. I think the current system is wasting the time of a ton more people than it takes for people to flag and delete comments, and I think people just don't care, because the people this affects are completely voiceless until they pass the threshold I finally passed. And then when they speak up, nobody wants to find a solution to the problem. 

What would *you* do to solve this problem, if you took it seriously?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, I think you should probably answer my question, too, if you are ever going to understand my position on this: do you think it makes sense for only straight A students to be able to ask questions of teachers in class, after they've given an example that is unclear? This is the current SO setup when it comes to comments, so the answers to these problems will be the same.

Comment: @lead: you may be right. Maybe tons of possible new users would love to able to comment and would benefit of it. But the number of people who can spend a part of their private time in posting answers and moderating this site is not large enough. And as far as I am concerned, I believe I have spent a lot of time in helping other users here. I have done it willingly because SO helped me a lot when I had to learn new technologies, and I wanted to give back what I recieved.  But I cannot spend more time here, that is the reason why I cannot support anything that would require more moderation time.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, you do not actually know that it would increase moderation time.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, for example: people with high reputation points who leave improper comments that have to be moderated out already exist. With a separate comment reputation point stream, these people would be penalized an would possibly learn not to leave these comments. Or they'd be restricted from being able to leave them. The net effect could be a dramatic *decrease* in moderation time. But you don't know that, because it hasn't been tested out.

Comment: @Security Hound, while I was going about my day, I found this question, answer, and subsequent commentary, which perfectly illustrate the utility of comments, why they shouldn't always be separate answers, and I think you can imagine how new users could benefit from participation in this: [way more efficient than new questions or answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11346337/9237603)

Comment: @lead - I honestly only see commentary asking a new question and commentary replying to that question.  That initial commentary should have been submitted as a new question

Comment: @Security Hound, that sounds like a nightmare to track down the answer to. It's relevant to the question, it would have improved the answer. If anything had changed about how that went down, I think the answer should have been edited to include that. Other than that, that is exactly the most efficient way for SO to work.

Answer (score 20):

The 50 reputation point requirement for comments is to prevent spam. Comments are harder to get rid of than questions and answers; in most cases it takes a moderator to get rid of them.

Your proposal would give a spam account 5 comments immediately and allow them to give themselves more by creating other accounts to up vote their own comments.

This would require re-creating the voting system currently used for posts for comments, including detection of fraudulent voting activity. Since it would be impossible for just a handful of diamond moderators to manage the flood of spam, it would also require new flags, delete votes for comments, review queues, etc. so that the community can help moderate comments.

That's an awful lot of developer effort up front to permanently increase the moderation workload on the community.

If you can figure out a way to lower or remove the reputation requirement without increasing the amount of spam or the amount of moderation required, you'd probably get some support.

Comment: **Moderator note:** Rude comments to this answer were deleted. Nobody is expected to have a discussion with you in the comments before answering. When you post a question on Meta, you're inviting the community to weigh in with their opinions, which should be done in the form of answers.

Comment: I don't think it's only that though; I have always seen the staged unlocking of site features as a way to introduce people to the site and slowly get the lay of the land, to prevent them immediately diving off a cliff or stepping into a sinkhole. Commenting is just one of the many things that can be easily abused when you haven't seen and understood the rules.

Comment: @Cody Gray you've proved that it's not at all hard to delete comments. None of my comments were rude that you deleted.

Comment: @lead Your first comment was indeed rude, insulting, and dismissive of BSMP's answer; I reviewed it myself. Yes, it is easy for moderators to delete comments. We do so frequently.

Comment: @Cody Gray, considering "it's almost impossible to delete comments" is the most common reason given for not allowing a separate track of comment reputation, I don't understand what you're trying to say here.

Comment: No one has ever given that as a reason. They've said that *moderating* comments is difficult, because there are no tools for it. I don't want to sign up to review each and every incoming comment; do you? Deleting is easy, but I don't want to have to go around deleting more comments than I already do. I have better things to do with my life. If you haven't yet contributed in even a *trivial* way to this site, enough to earn the privilege to comment, then you can either do so or not do so, but you don't get to post a comment. @lead

Comment: @Cody I'm observing your cynicism in another recently asked question about chats. People are pointing out that there's this whole need for discussion for new users, and you're ignoring it. I suspect you'd have less moderation and less *arguing* you'd have to do if you had comment reputation points and rate limiting. Lots of the comments from sufficiently reputationed people are apparently garbage, and putting a lot of work on your plate already. Why not make the site more functional and accessible for new users while also lightening your work load?

Comment: It doesn't even come *close* to lightening the work load. Do you know how much work it is to moderate chat? The best way to lighten the workload is to have a minimum reputation requirement. This is exactly what we have. It isn't about cynicism in any way. If you want to go discuss things, there are zillions of other sites on the Internet to do that. You don't need to use Stack Overflow. @lead

Comment: @Cody Gray, you seem to be misunderstanding my proposal, and also not really engaging with the other proposal enough to figure out a way for it to work well. (I can think of a bunch). My proposal is to have comments limited by a separate amount of reputation specific to good commenting. I can't think of a reason why this wouldn't lighten your work load. If somebody makes a ton of bad comments, they would lose comment access, even if they still had points to leave answers, etc. How does this increase your load?

Answer (score 10):

Although I understand that not being able to comment can be frustrating for a new user, I do not think that the rule deserves to be changed.

Because comments are not first class citizens on SO. They are here to ask clarification or to help the authors to improve their post. Questions and answers stay there with all their edits and are managed by the community (up/down voted and if needed can be closed and deleted by the community). Comments are not. IMHO an example of a very useful comment is a comment that proposes an improvement to an answer, that is used by the answerer and immediately deleted because non longer needed. How would you want to handle that? How to automatically distinguish it from an erroneous one that is deleted the same, once its author realizes that they wrote a stupid thing?

That means that adding a rep. counter for comments is not that easy. And (still IMHO) it is not really useful either. Any poster can comment on their own post, and earning 50 rep. points to be allowed to comment on any post is not that hard. English is not the first language for a lot of users, and it is easy to propose edits to just fix language errors. And even if it is not a major improvement, it does improve the global site quality.

Moreover, your last examples are good reasons to not change anything. If you intend to use a comment to give a slight improvement to an answer, please do not. Or more exactly do not expect it to remain only in a comment. If the answer author uses it to improve their post, it is fine, and you can just remove your post. If they do not, then the best way is to post a new answer explaining that it is a complement to the other answer. And if you want to ask clarifications on an answer because you cannot understand to use it on your actual context, do not use a comment. Here again the good way is to ask a new question with a reference to the other one and explaining why you could not use it and what your precise question is. It may be answered in comments if it was really trivial and if nothing needs to be added to the other answers, but it can also deserves a new answer, either on your own question or on the original one. But being a new question, it will receive a higher audience than a comment on an older post.

Long story made short, I am still not sure than the current way of handling comments on SO is the possible best, but I am sure to disagree with your proposal.

Comment: Not added to the answer, because I know that it is questionnable, but I have already seen new users using answers to ask good questions to OP. And every time I see one, I make a comment with it (leaving the original commenter name) and ask the poster to delete their own (non) answer.

Comment: It's pretty easy to add a flag functionality for why a comment was deleted. Furthermore the organizational strategy you're proposing (one that invalidates the purpose of comments) is a nightmare. I do not want telescoping questions on this site when all I need is a slightly better answer to an existing question! Higher levels of exposure do not make it easier for users to find the answer to their question, it just creates a mess of similar questions to have to sort through. This is the entire purpose of upvotes! Your answer is bad but I can't downvote yet.

Comment: @lead: This is the purpose of answers on Meta: let the community vote to decide what is prefered by contributors. BTW, when I find a comment on a answer of mine asking more details, I often advise to ask a new question with a [mcve] because it is essential to understand a problem. A comment may only be enough for trivial things.

Comment: The problem with all of the logic of people here is that it creates an exclusive, self-definitional club of people. People who have success in the system defend against changes to the system, for no good reason that I have yet to see. I, for example, cannot downvote your answer yet. I wish I could, but I didn't set those rules. And if things keep up the way they are, I won't be able to any time soon.

Comment: @lead You fail to take into account that we all started with 1 reputation point here. Plus, when you gain enough points on one SE site, you get enough on the others to comment and vote right away. It's not too difficult to earn the first 50 points, editing is a stable way to get there, but good answers would get there much faster. But please stop being rude against other users.

Comment: @lead You are right on one point: SO lives through a community of people who agree on some rules. Among those rules, one says that to be able to fully participate, new users have to prove that they accept to do some efforts by earning some rep. And the more rep, the more tools. Then rules can evolve *provided a majority of the community agree on the change*. I believe that you sincerely  want to improve the site with simply commenting, and it can make sense. And you were right in posting a question on meta to propose it...

Comment: ...  But the votes, comments and answers say that the majority of active members think that the risk (spams and increase in moderation task) if higher than the benefit (good comments from newcomers). I would be glad that you can comment anywhere and even downvote this answer. But as others and I have already said, it it easy to earn 50 rep points, and that is the only way to go if you want it.

Comment: @ModusTollens, I didn't fail to take anything into account. You are a group of people who have self-selected for commentary in this community, and you are systematically being hostile to the people who disagree with you, because none of them can upvote or comment in this meta. You are wrong about how SE works. I have had enough points on a bunch of other sites to comment and upvote for a long time now, and non on SO. What you are describing as "easy" is really "easy for you".

Comment: @Serge Ballesta, the community of opinions you describe is self-selected. Your logic is circular. The people who can comment and up and downvote are all people who are bound to not have had the problems and barriers that I am describing here. You cannot point to a group that is systematically biased against a change in the system as proof that the system shouldn't change.

Comment: @lead - Every single user who can submit a comment, were new users at one point in time, and were unable to submit a comment until they had the reputation to do so.  You earn reputation by submitting questions or answers.  You do not earn reputation by submitting commentary, and for that reason, any commentary you might submit is consider to be temporary.  Most comments I flag are not helpful, and I flag hundreds of comments daily, while most are some form of a "thank you" others are commentary from other users asking their own questions

Comment: @Security Hound, I'm aware it's all tempory, and I didn't propose having comments contribute to reputation points. What I *did* propose is that there be a separate track of reputation points for comments to people could be regulated in this particular venue of participation without it impacting the rest of the site. I think you'll find that there are a whole bunch of people who would make it through to higher reputation points if they could integrate into the site via comments first.